# How does use strict impact this keyword in the context of call and apply method of a Function object in Javascript ES5 and ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this

I want know  the concept of **this** in use strict mode , in the context of  call and apply method of a Function object in Javascript ES5 and ES6. A good example with explanation will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If a function is *strict*, its `this` value is not converted to an object but kept as it is. For non-strict functions, `this` is always converted to an object (unless it is `null` or `undefined` of course):

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(typeof this);
}
function foo_strict() {
  "use strict";
  console.log(typeof this);
}

foo.call(42);
foo_strict.call(42);
```